# netlogo turtles moving on coordinates

Tags: coordinates, netlogo, turtle-graphics

I created turtles called "birds" that shall move on a specific route. The route is made out of links between turtles I called "rasts". As I couldn't find a way to make the turtles move from the first rast to the second, third, fourth and fifth, I changed the rasts an created them as patches.
So, now I have patches in red (rests).

How do I get the birds moving to exactly these patches and, when they are at the patch, how do I make them go to the next one?

I have no code at the moment, because I always hope to find the fault in my first model (see my other questions).

Is there anybody who knows how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

the `move-to` command moves your turtle to any other turtle or patch you specify. You can also use the `face` and `forward` commands to gradually move along a route (see the 'Move Towards Target' code example in the Models Library that comes with NetLogo)